# Automation regarding Flow Tests

Tags: visual-workflow, visual-flows

Flow tests are not enforced and neither is coverage. As functionality across the org is migrated to flows, what is the best way to build automation around Flow tests.

How do we ensure quality across suite of Flow tests across the org?

Do we:

1. Have equivalent Apex tests for each Flow test? (Hard to maintain)
2. Invoke flows in Apex tests
3. Use tooling API and execute flow tests on some schedule

Any other way?

Comment: are you talking about the newly-introduced [Flow Test](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_test.htm&type=5) ?  Note that Screen Flows can be tested using UX testing tools like Copado Robotic Testing or Provar

Comment: Yes I was referring to other type of flows like record trigger flows etc.

Comment: personally, I'd wait until SFDC adds regression test on deployment functionality for Flow Tests unless you have some "hot spot" record-triggered flows wherein some good apex testmethods can serve as a regression test platform